# Maple: Ignore higher order terms in a polynomial with fraction exponents

Tags: polynomials, maple, exponent

I am trying to ignore higher order exponents in polynomial on Maple. This is an example of what I have[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NpoG.png)

I would want my mapping to return 1 + $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ +x^3+x$^{\frac{7}{2}}$. It seems like the map completely ignores any fraction exponents...

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt using `degree` doesn't work because of the following,

```
degree(x^(7/2),x);

       FAIL
```

With the terms all being powers of `x` you could handle that example with,

```
remove(t->type(t,identical(x)^rational)
       and op(2,t)>4, m);

   1+x^(1/2)+x^3+x^(7/2)
```

If you have other kinds of example then you could share them; adjustments are possible.

[edit] If you relax that strict inequality so as also to disallow `x^4`, then you could also get by with the following (which is also convenient if you have coefficients):

```
m := 1 + x^(1/2) + x^3 + x^(7/2)
     + x^6 + x^4 + x^(199/2):

convert(series(m,x,4),polynom);

    1+x^(1/2)+x^3+x^(7/2)
```

Compare with,

```
remove(t->type(t,identical(x)^rational)
       and op(2,t)>=4, m);

    1+x^(1/2)+x^3+x^(7/2)
```

Comment: I used the convert one and it worked - thank you !!